# How do I loop through divs with left and right buttons?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to loop through 6 divs with the left and right buttons, the idea is that you can move left and right and the selected div would have the class 'active' and then when you click left or right it would move to the next div along and remove the class from the previous div and add it to the next one along the line.

**This is my Js**

```
 $(function () { // this is a shortcut for document ready
    var stuff = ['box1', 'box2', 'box3', 'box4', 'box5','box6'],
        counter = 0;

    console.log(stuff[counter]); // your initial value


    $('.right').click(function () {
        counter = (counter + 1) % stuff.length;
        valueNw = stuff[counter];
        console.log(valueNw); 
    });
    $('.left').click(function () {
        counter = (counter - 1) % 1;
        console.log(stuff[counter]); 
    });


});
```

[codePen](http://codepen.io/MrJoshFisher/pen/VmaxyR?editors=0011#0)

Any ideas would be appreciated, I've got it to go forwards but not backwards, if there is a better way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: Are you hoping for continuous loop or not have left enabled on first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is in response to your question in @Pranav's answer. This is how I would select divs based on right/left button click.

```
var eleName = ".box1";
var eleCount = 0;
var currIndex = 1;

$(function () { // this is a shortcut for document ready
     eleCount = $('.box').length;
     $(eleName).toggleClass('active');
     ShowConsoleInfo();

  $('.right').click(function () {
        if(currIndex <= eleCount - 1){
          //Toggle current box.
          $(eleName).toggleClass('active');
          //Build the name by incrementing current index.
          currIndex++;
          eleName = '.box' + currIndex;
          //Toggle newly selected box.
          $(eleName).toggleClass('active');
          ShowConsoleInfo();
        }
    });

    $('.left').click(function () {
        if(currIndex >= 2){
          //Toggle current box.
          $(eleName).toggleClass('active');
          //Build the name by decrementing current index.
          currIndex--;
          eleName = '.box' + currIndex;
          //Toggle newly selected box.
          $(eleName).toggleClass('active');
          ShowConsoleInfo();
        }
    });
});

function ShowConsoleInfo(){
    console.clear();
    console.log("Current Index: " + currIndex);
    console.log("Element Count: " + eleCount);
    console.log("Current Box name: " + eleName);
};
```

See the Pen [Right Left Div Selection Example [jQuery]](http://codepen.io/BOORDA/pen/ZBWMBK/) by Addam Boord ([@BOORDA](http://codepen.io/BOORDA)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

Answer (score 1):

In your code `(counter - 1) % 1` would always result `0` so it always points to `0`. Instead, change the backward condition to avoid negative values by replacing value to `stuff.length` in case `counter` is `0`.

```js
$(function() { // this is a shortcut for document ready
  var stuff = ['box1', 'box2', 'box3', 'box4', 'box5', 'box6'],
    counter = 0;

  console.log(stuff[counter]); // your initial value


  $('.right').click(function() {
    counter = (counter + 1) % stuff.length;
    valueNw = stuff[counter];
    console.log(valueNw);
  });
  $('.left').click(function() {
    // replace with stuff.length if counter holds 0 and decrement
    counter = (counter || stuff.length) - 1;
    console.log(stuff[counter]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="right">right</button>
<button class="left">left</button>
```

Comment: Cheers worked a charm now one quick one how would I do this to the boxes ? I get addClass remove Class but how would you do that ?

Comment: No as in the 6 divs in the codepen, I want to move between theme so it starts at 1 and the left and right buttons would add class active to the next or previous one and remove the class from it when its not active.

Comment: @MrJoshFisher : select all and remove class after add class using index.... select element using `eq()` method